# Expresion Regular de servidor y dominio en Email

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito una expresion regular que me permita validar el dominio de la compañia en el input:

Me explico: la personas que vayan hacer un registro en el formulario no puedan colocar un correo diferente al de la compania

Comment: Rafael, por favor comparte con nosotros lo que hasta ahora intentaste. Edita tu pregunta y agrega ligas a otros recursos que consultaste, **tu código**, lo que piensas que origina el error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que el dominio tienen un patrón para asignar las direcciones de correo electrónico, por ejemplo:

```
apellido.nombre@dominioempresa.com
```

Para el caso anterior la forma de validarlo en Javascript es con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
let re = /[a-z]+\.[a-z]+@dominioempresa\.com/
```

Si en cambio el formato del correo electrónico es de tipo:

```
nombre.123@dominioempresa.com
```

La expresión regular sería:

```
let re = /^[a-z]+\.[0-9]+@dominioempresa\.com$/
```

En ambos casos es muy importante escapar los puntos y utilizar el acento circunflejo (^) al inicio y el símbolo de dólar ($) al finalizar, de modo que busque toda la expresión de forma exacta.

Y luego hay que aplicar un método ya sea para la cadena a validar o a la expresión regular para ver si hay coincidencia.